# Цикл While выдаёт по много копий одного и того же юзера, что делать?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$rid = result['id']; - результат айди группы, определяет группу.

$subs_gr = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `group_subs` INNER JOIN users ON u_id = users.id WHERE g_id = {$rid} AND u_id AND status = 1  LIMIT 6");/*Вывод списка подписчиков в группе 6*/
$gr_sub = mysqli_fetch_array($subs_gr);/**/
```

Вот запрос в sql

и вывожу данные через

```
while($gr_sub){
<div class='name'>{$gr_sub['name']}</div>

итд.
}
```

Comment: `LIMIT 6` выводит не подписчиков группы 6, а 6 случайных подписчиков из всех, соответствующих условиям отбора.

Comment: Мне кажется в цикл нужно передавать не результат, потому-что он всегда будет верным, а присваивание. `while($gr_sub = mysqli_fetch_array($subs_gr);)`

Comment: @Akina Вы немного неправильно выразились. `LIMIT` ограничивает кол-во возвращаемых записей. В данном случае запрос с данным ограничением просто вернет первые 6 записей, вне зависимости от того по каким условиям и по какому полю они будут отсортированы.

Comment: @user413219 Сортировка в запросе отсутствует. Так что о какой-либо сортировке речи не идёт в принципе. Будет некий физический порядок записей в памяти сервера (возможно, вообще не напоминающий никакую сортировку), вот по этому порядку первые 6 записей и вернутся.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

> Возвращает массив, соответствующий обработанному ряду результата запроса и сдвигает внутренний указатель данных вперед.

```php
$subs_gr = mysqli_query( ... );
while($gr_sub = mysqli_fetch_array($subs_gr) ){
<div class='name'>{$gr_sub['name']}</div>

итд.
}
```